# Como acessar o Editor de Temas do Android Studio na versão 3.3.1?

Tags: android-studio

**Estou editando essa pergunta por que acredito que muitos *devs* devem ter passado pelo mesmo problema: "Não encontrar o Editor de Temas no AS".**

Na [documentação do Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor) você encontra o seguinte:

> Conceitos básicos do Theme Editor
>
> Esta seção descreve como acessar o
>   Theme Editor e como é o seu layout.
>
> Acessar o Theme Editor
>
> Há duas formas de abrir o Theme Editor:
>
> Em um arquivo XML de estilos aberto, como styles.xml, clique em Open
>   editor perto do canto superior direito da janela do arquivo. No menu
>   Tools, clique em Android > Theme Editor.

Mas como salientado na pergunta original e pela imagem, não é possivel encontrar o Editor de Temas, mesmo que siga as orientações da documentação.

[image: theme editor não encontrado]

Comment: Acredito que muitos devs devem ter passado pelo mesmo problema: "Não encontrar o Editor de Temas no AS". Na central de ajuda do SO diz que: "se a sua pergunta tem a ver com... ferramentas comuns entre programadores... então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta". Se possível, gostaria que fosse reaberta para que eu possa respondê-la!

Comment: @LeonardoCosta eu posso reabrir ou só a comunidade pode?

Answer (score 2):

#### Atualização

Segundo as respostas do [problema reportado no Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119271605) o **Theme Editor foi desativado** a partir da versão **3.3 Beta** do Android Studio.
Uma das respostas ainda cita um [post no reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/av3lhx/were_on_the_engineering_team_for_android_studio/ehhmt5q/), no qual um Project Manager do  Android Studio diz:

> "Unfortunately we had to disable the Theme Editor due to performance issues, complexity of maintenance on top of low usage.. We are working on a better alternative."

Que traduzido seria +/- isso:

> "Infelizmente tivemos que desativar o Theme Editor devido a problemas com desempenho, complexidade de manutenção além de baixo uso... Estamos trabalhando em uma melhor alternativa"

Por esse motivo você não esta encontrando em sua versão de Android Studio, e parece que eles esqueceram de colocar essa informação no site [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor).

Caso essa *feature* seja realmente necessária para seu projeto, você pode tentar baixar/usar uma versão anterior a essa, [Esta página](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) fornece um arquivo das versões do Android Studio.
<sup>*mas lembre-se que a recomendação deles é a utilização da [versão estável mais recente](https://developer.android.com/studio/) ou da [versão de visualização mais recente](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/).</sup>

---

Segundo o [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor)

> ## Acessar o Theme Editor
>
> Há duas formas de abrir o Theme Editor:
>
> 1. Em um arquivo `XML` de estilos aberto, como **styles.xml**, clique em <kbd>Open editor</kbd> perto do canto superior direito da janela do arquivo.
> 2. No menu <kbd>Tools</kbd>, clique em <kbd>Android</kbd> > <kbd>Theme Editor</kbd>.

Se não esta parecendo pode ter ocorrido algum problema na sua instalação/atualização.

Um outra coisa que você pode tentar fazer é restaurar o padrão dos menus e toolbars para ver se volta a aparecer.
<sub>**[Nota]: Nunca fiz isso, mas no seu caso pode ser útil.**</sub>

Passo para restaurar o padrão dos menus e toolbars:

1. Clique em <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> na barra superior do android studio.
2. Uma nova janela irá surgir nela você vai entrar em <kbd>Apparence & Behavior</kbd> > <kbd>Menus and Toolbars</kbd>
3. Clique em <kbd>Restore All Defaults</kbd>.

<sub>Imagem da Janela **Apparence & Behavior** > **Menus and Toolbars**</sub>
[image: Apparence & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars]

Comment: Vou reinstalar o android studio pq a opções "Restore All Defaults" está inabilitada para clicar, e n tenho nem uma ideia de como resoulver.

Comment: depois de reinstalar, entrando no menu do seu print Screen, o "Theme Editor" aparace, mas não no "main menu/ tool" para poder usar-lo.

Comment: Se ele aparece na janela do print screen, então você deve conseguir utilizar usando um dos 2 metodos de acessar descrito no site do android developers. Tente acessar clicando em **Tools** > **Android** > **Theme Editor** na barra superior do android studio.

Comment: não está aparecendo nos lugares indicados, só lá mesmo

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer o seguinte, nesta janela mudar o **Theme Editor** de local/posição e verificar e ele vai aparecer na nova local/posição que você escolheu, se ainda assim ele não aparecer, apos essa mudança o botão `Restore All Defaults` esteja clicavel, clicar nele pode ser outro teste.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem duas possibilidades:

1. No arquivo XML de estilos aberto, como "styles.xml", clique em
   Open editor perto do canto superior direito da janela do arquivo.

ou

2. No menu Tools, clique em Android > Theme Editor.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: não tem mais essas duas opções